# ActionController::UnpermittedParameters in StaplesController#create when I aply nested_attributes with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I'm desperate... I had tried all advices from all possible relevant sources I found, but nothing helps. I'm using ruby 2.0.0 rails 4.1.8 and nested_form gem.

It still produces the same error:

### **ActionController::UnpermittedParameters in StaplesController#create**

### **found unpermitted parameters: cqnames**

I have model **Staple**:

```
class Staple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :allergens
  has_many :cqnames, as: :cqnable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cqnames, allow_destroy: true
  translates :name, :description
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

with association **has_and_belongs_to_many** to model **Allergen**:

```
class Allergen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staples
  translates :name, :annex
  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

(it works fine...) and with **polymorphic association** to model **Cqname**:

```
class Cqname < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cqnable, polymorphic: true
end
```

with permitting of nested_attributes in **staples_controller.rb**:

```
  private
    def set_staple
      @staple = Staple.find(params[:id])
    end

    def staple_params
      params.require(:staple).permit(:name, :description, allergen_ids: [], cqnames_attributes: [:id, :name, :language, :description, :_destroy] )
    end
```

Here is the content of the error screen (produced when the existing staple is updating):

**ActionController::UnpermittedParameters in StaplesController#update**

**found unpermitted parameters: cqnames**

Extracted source (around line #68):

```
66 |
67 |     def staple_params
68 |         params.require(:staple).permit(:name, :description, allergen_ids: [], cqnames_attributes: [:id, :name, :language, :description, :_destroy] )
69 |     end
70 |  end
```

app/controllers/staples_controller.rb:68:in 'staple_params'
app/controllers/staples_controller.rb:40:in 'update'

**Request**

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MdufJeUWmoNdJaEeP/ReIxOY+TLthJ9yIUD9aI15Htg=",
 "staple"=>{"name"=>"Syr",
 "description"=>"Nejaká tá mliečna dobrôtka.",
 "allergen_ids"=>["1",
 "2",
 "3",
 ""],
 "cqnames_attributes"=>{"1428061910570"=>{"cqnames"=>{"name"=>"aaa",
 "language"=>"bbb",
 "description"=>"ccc",
 "_destroy"=>""}}}},  
 "commit"=>"Update Staple",  
 "locale"=>"en",  
 "id"=>"2"}
```

and here the **_form.html.erb** for model **Staple**:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@staple) do |f| %>
  <% if @staple.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= t('errors.template.header', count: @staple.errors.size, model: t('activerecord.models.staple')) %></h2>

      <ul>
        <% @staple.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.association :allergens, as: :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :cqnames %>
    <div data-no-turbolink><%= f.link_to_add "Add a colloquial name", :cqnames %></div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with **_cqname_fields.html.erb**:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><%= _("Colloquial Name") %></legend>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :cqnames do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :name %>
    <%= builder.input :language %>
    <%= builder.input :description, as: :text %>
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove this colloquial name" %>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

Help me please if you know...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks... It was only misapplied **simple_fields_for** method in **_form.html.erb** and **_cqname_fields.html**

right version are...

**_form.html.erb**:

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.association :allergens, as: :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :cqnames do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'cqname_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <div data-no-turbolink><p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a colloquial name", :cqnames %></p></div>
  </div>
```

and **_cqname_fields.html**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><%= _("Colloquial Name") %></legend>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :language %>
    <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
    <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this colloquial name" %>
</fieldset>
```

Now everything works fine... ;-)